# NSString sizeWithAttributes: returns different height in iOS 8 versus iOS 7

Tags: ios8

The line below returns a size with a larger height when I run it on an iOS8 device versus iOS7.  It happens regardless of whether I'm building with iOS 7 or iOS 8 as my base SDK. Anyone else seeing this issue?

```
return [myString sizeWithAttributes:attributes];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered my own question. The issue occurs when the string ends in a line break as below.  This causes an issue because iOS 7 ignores trailing line breaks but iOS 8 doesn't.

```
myString = @"Some text.\n";
```

Removing the trailing line breaks before calling sizeWithAttributes: fixes the problem.