# CGSize gives different values for ios version 7 and 8

Tags: ios, cgsize

I am using this code that results in deferent values for the different version of the ios.

```
CGSize textSize = [title sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f]}];
```

Comment: And what is the question? Do you want them to return the same value?
Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855472/nsstring-sizewithattributes-returns-different-height-in-ios-8-versus-ios-7

Comment: for the same text it should return same value for both ios version 7 and 8 but its returns different

Comment: i am not using any line break , using simple text as "abc"

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code:

```
NSString* title = @"Hey nonny nonny we like to party";
CGSize textSize = [title sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f]}];
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGSize(textSize));
```

I got these results. iOS 7:

```
2015-05-22 07:50:22.266 Test[1153:607] {214.49399999999994, 16.701999999999998}
```

iOS 8:

```
2015-05-22 07:49:57.957 Test[1090:31606] {214.49399999999994, 16.701999999999998}
```

Looks the same to me. I would have to guess there is something wrong with your testing procedure.